# How to obtain shiny-server version info in Ubuntu?

Tags: r, ubuntu, shiny, shiny-server

How do I check the version of shiny-server that is installed on an Ubuntu system?

Background:
Have installed shiny-server on Ubuntu14 32bit virtual machine (i.e. build from source). It is up and running, but not yet working well, and for searching solutions to my issues I need to know shiny-server version.

Answer (score 9):

`apt-cache showpkg shiny-server` is one option.